# Cannot empty array in ReastJS useEffect hook

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I'm having this table view in React where I fetch an array from API and display it. When the user types something on the table search box, I'm trying to clear the current state array and render the completely new result. But for some reason, the result keeps getting appended to the current set of results.

Here's my code:

```
const Layout = () => {

  var infiniteScrollTimeout = true;
  const [apiList, setapiList] = useState([]);

  //invoked from child.
  const search = (searchParameter) => {
    //Clearing the apiList to load new one but the console log after setApiList still logs the old list
    setapiList([]); // tried setApiList([...[]]), copying the apiList to another var and emptying it and then setting it too.
    console.log(apiList); //logs the old one.
    loadApiResults(searchParameter);
  };

  let url =
    AppConfig.api_url + (searchParameter || "");

  const loadApiResults = async (searchParameter) => {

    let response = await fetch(url + formurlencoded(requestObject), {
      method: "get",
      headers: headers,
    });
    let ApiResult = await response.json(); // read response body and parse as JSON

    if (ApiResult.status == true) {
      //Set the url for next fetch when user scrolls to bottom.
      url = ApiResult.next_page_url + (searchParameter || "");

      let data;
      data = ApiResult.data;

      setapiList([...data]);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    loadApiResults();

    document.getElementById("myscroll").addEventListener("scroll", () => {
      if (
        document.getElementById("myscroll").scrollTop +
          document.getElementById("myscroll").clientHeight >=
        document.getElementById("myscroll").scrollHeight - 10
      ) {
        if (infiniteScrollTimeout == true) {
          console.log("END OF PAGE");
          loadApiResults();
          infiniteScrollTimeout = false;
          setTimeout(() => {
            infiniteScrollTimeout = true;
          }, 1000);
        }
      }
    });
  }, []);


  return (
    <ContentContainer>
      <Table
        ...
      />
    </ContentContainer>
  );
};
export default Layout;
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I do see a brief moment of the state being reset, on calling the loadApiResult again after resetting the state. The old state comes back. If I remove the call to loadApiResult, the table render stays empty.

Comment: State's changes are assynchonous, logging the old state from inside `useEffect` will always show the current state, not the new one. Log outside your effect and you should see the updated version.

Comment: @Dupocas there is a log outside the useEffect inside search() function as well.

Answer (score 0):

add apiList in array as the second parameter in useEffect

Comment: Adding apiList as the second param will cause useEffect to endlessly keep fetching the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [dependencies feature](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect) in your `useEffect` function

```
const [searchParameter, setSearchParameter] = useState("");
... mode code ...

useEffect(() => {
  loadApiResults();

  ... more code ...
}, [searchParameter]);
```

`useEffect` will automatically trigger whenever the value of searchParameter changes, assuming your input uses `setSearchParameter` on change